# How to execute procedure returning dynamic column using Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures, entity-framework-5, objectcontext, executestorequery

I am executing a procedure using following code.

```
SqlParameter LTParam = new SqlParameter("@LearningTrackID",learningTrackID);
dynamic LTReport = objectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<dynamic>(
                  "exec usp_LearningTrackReport @LearningTrackID", LTParam);
```

The procedure usp_LearningTrackReport returns dynamic output depending upon the parameter passed.

The number of columns of the table returned by procedure varies every time depending on parameter.

I need to capture the result in C# Object, so that I can view them as report on the screen. I tried executing above mentioned code, it executes without any error but does not returns anything.

I am using Entity Framework 5.

In case any body has already Implemented such functionality please help.5